# My Discord bot is not working on a second server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wrote a Discord bot with `discord.js` and `enmap.js`.
Everything works on my Discord server. I put everything up on a VPS Server and it still works on my Discord Server.

Now I put it on a second Discord Server and the commands are not working on the second server.

I get this error:

```
(node:9131) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
    at GuildMember.addRole (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildMember.js:452:38)
    at Client.client.on (/root/masterbot/mainl.js:149:43)
    at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/root/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (/root/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:137:47)
(node:9131) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
```

I don't really know what I'm reading here. :D

Comment: I don't get anything when I go to the provided page. Please post the error message here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says:

```
(node:9131) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
    at GuildMember.addRole (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildMember.js:452:38)
    at Client.client.on (/root/masterbot/mainl.js:149:43)
```

It means that you're calling [`GuildMember.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) with a wrong argument. Try checking your `mainl.js` file, at line 149.

Comment: Thank you, I think I used the ID from that role instead of searching for that role. Of course that couldn't work. This role has a complete other ID on a different server